# Tensorflow/nvidia/cuda docker mismatched versions

Tags: docker, tensorflow, cuda, nvidia

I am trying to use tensorflow and nvidia with docker, but hitting the following error:

> docker run --runtime=nvidia -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu    python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
>
> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"process_linux.go:407: running prestart hook 1 caused \\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: exec command: [/usr/bin/nvidia-container-cli --load-kmods configure --ldconfig=@/sbin/ldconfig.real --device=all --compute --utility --require=cuda>=10.0 brand=tesla,driver>=384,driver<385 --pid=5393 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/......./merged]\\nnvidia-container-cli: requirement error: unsatisfied condition: brand = tesla\\n\\"\"": unknown.

I get similar error when trying to run nvidia-smi:

> docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi

but when trying to run nvidia-smi with cuda:9.0-base, it works like a charm:

> docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda:9.0-base nvidia-smi

Do I need to make sure that cuda 10 works or I can run tensorflow with cuda 9? And how can I run the docker image of tensorflow with cuda:9.0-base? (still a docker newby).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Ok I think I am finally starting to figure out the mess on my machine.

The tensorflow image does NOT care about the cuda image version, it does not use the docker cuda image. It cares about my nvidia drivers, since it has CUDA integrated in the tensorflow image.

(The docker cuda image that is working with my current drivers, is cuda:9.0)

That meant I have to find a tensorflow image that is working with my drivers (390.116), or update the drivers.

I tried the same command with tensorflow:1.12.0-gpu-py3, and it didn't have any problems.

Comment: To add to your answer. The nvidia-driver that comes with each level of CUDA can be used with any container that has that level of CUDA or an older level of CUDA on it. Using a new nvidia-driver and an older CUDA level will work. Using a older nvidia-driver and newer CUDA level will not work.

Comment: tensorflow-gpu is linked against a particular CUDA version, so it **does** care about the cuda version.  You must have the proper CUDA version, and you need a driver that is supportive of that CUDA version.  Your docker image "does not care" because it has the necessary CUDA version already installed.  A particular CUDA version has [a minimum driver version required](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html) (scroll down to table 1), but it can be used with drivers that are newer than that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, but not explained correctly. Will edit my answer.